# Can I use vim from host to edit files inside docker container? If yes then how?

Tags: docker, vim, visual-studio-code, editor, remote-access

I have a project on which we have set up a development environment using `docker-compose`. We are using `volumes` to sync files from host to docker containers. The performance for **sync** is kinda **bad on Mac**. 
I recently saw some extension for VS code which allows you to edit files inside the docker container. Here is the [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) to that extension.
Can I do something similar with vim?

Thanks a lot in advance!

I tried to `ssh` into docker container but I wasn't successful. I will have to use `docker exec` to ssh into it.

Comment: you must configure your `ssh` in docker  and then use `https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim`

Answer (score 0):

You can use vim to edit the files remotely provided that you have the SSH access to that container. In order to get that, you'll have to generate and place SSH keys on your machine and the public keys inside the container. But, you need to have SSH server running inside the container and the SSH port exposed.

If editing the file from the host machine using Vim is the absolute requirement, this is the way to go.

But, if you only want to make the debugging easier, consider using [Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). You bind the target file from your host machiner and edit it locally. The container accessing your file will immediately see the changes reflected inside it.

Comment: The problem with bind mounts is its performance is very bad on mac. If it would have been windows or Linux Machine, it would work.

Comment: @PraveenDhawan: What do you mean that the performance is bad? Is there any specific problem that you're facing?

Comment: @7-r3x See this https://forums.docker.com/t/painfully-slow/32078. There are a couple of forums in the community about docker's bad performance in syncing on Mac. We have webpacker which compiles all the frontend JS and CSS and this syncing of files becomes really slow when we do change in those files.